# get html from webpage using IPv6 address and javascript

Tags: javascript, http, ipv6

I was wondering if there was a way to use JavaScript to get a httpGet request from a IPv6 address.

I've set up a virtual mesh network using cooja on my home computer, each node has an IPv6 address in the form of `aaaa::0212:740x:000x:0x0x` where x is the node number.

When using a normal jquery request:

```
$.ajax({ url: url,
 success: function(data) 
 {console.log(data); } 
});
```

a website eg http://www.random.org/intergers/?etc, will get a random number back and log it, however when a ipv6 address is put in ie [aaaa::0212:740x:000x:0x0x] it doesnt give me back anything, no errors, no response, nothing.

Can anybody shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Perhaps it or its network doesn't support IPv6 for domain resolution?

Comment: if you visit the url in the browser, using the IPv6 domain, do is work?

Comment: This may be of use https://github.com/beaugunderson/javascript-ipv6

Comment: @RoryPicko92, Yes it does.

Comment: Sounds like you have run into the [same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/1068283) preventing you from doing what you think you want to do.

Comment: @RoryPicko92 - Tried using javascript-ipv6, not sure what I'm looking for there, I've tried running the basic code which verifies that its a valid IPv6 address and that its on the subnet. However I'm not too sure how this is suppose to help me with the http/GET req.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for a URL containing an IPv6 address is:

```
http://[2607:f8b0:4005:802::1010]/
```

The brackets are necessary to distinguish address components from a port number.

Comment: Thats right, which works when I place it in a web browsers url, but when i place it in an jquery ajax or get request, it doesnt seem to respond, with or without square brackets :/

Comment: @DarylRodrigo Have you tried sniff the request in the browser's developer tools ?

Comment: @VitorCanova, I did what you suggested and sniffed the http request to the IPv6. Looks like the IPv6 request is fine, as a response it gives (Status-Line) HTTP/1.0 200 OK except is missing Content-Enconding, Content-length and a whole bunch of other data. Any Ideas?

Comment: @DarylRodrigo Have you tried another ipv6 domain for example?